# Whats the difference between ofstream "<<" and Write

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file

I had opened a file in binary mode and like to write to an file .

```cpp
std::ofstream ofile("file.txt",ios_base::binary)
int a = 1;
float f = 0.1;
std::string str = 10;
ofile << a << f<< str;
```

I would like to know what is the difference between using `<<` and `ofile.write`.

Which is the best and effective to write in binary mode?

Comment: This is a total guess, but I'll bet `operator<<` is implemented using `write()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

operator<< will format your data as text.  Whereas write will output data in the same format as it's stored in ram.  So, if you are writing binary files, you want to use write.

However, if you are writing non-pod types, you need to be careful.  You can't just say:

```
write( &mystring, sizeof(std::string) );
```

You need to have some way to output the actual data, which is not stored in the class or struct itself.

Comment: I suspect it should of `write(&mystring, mystring.size())`

Comment: @Dilawar: No, that's even more wrong. The character data is not stored in the string object itself. It is dynamically allocated separately and referred to by a pointer. You can use `mystring.c_str()`, but you also need to store the size itself somehow if you want to be able to retrieve it correctly.

Comment: is `wrtie(&mystring, mystring.length())` any better? also `write("s\n", 2)` is ok? if yes then is it faster than `ofile << "s\n"`?

Comment: @platinoob_: No, `length()` and `size()` do exactly the same thing. `write("s\n", 2)` is fine, and it might be faster than `ofile << "s\n"`, since it doesn't have to figure out the length of the string. I doubt you'd be able to measure a difference though.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK write passes the value 'as is' where as the operator<< performs some formatting.

For more see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) it has bullet points listing some of the features.

As mentioned, for binary data is is generally preferable to use write as it just outputs the data without *any* formatting (which is very important for binary data as additional formatting may invalidate the format)